# NSIS MUI Icon in Programs and Features

Tags: nsis

I want to Show my custom icon in Windows Programs and Features. I have created a installer script through NSIS    *Below is my MUI userinterface settings*

```
; MUI Settings
!define MUI_ABORTWARNING
!define MUI_ICON ".\Include\Images\Icons\icon.ico"
!define MUI_UNICON ".\Include\Images\Icons\icon.ico"
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP ".\Include\Images\Header\header.bmp"
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_UNBITMAP ".\Include\Images\Header\header.bmp" 
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_RIGHT
!define MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP ".\Include\Images\Wizard\welcome.bmp"
!define MUI_UNWELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP ".\Include\Images\Wizard\welcome.bmp"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The icon must be registered as part of the uninstall values, you need to add a [DisplayIcon](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Add_uninstall_information_to_Add/Remove_Programs) string value that points to your .exe or .ico in `$InstDir`.

```
Section
WriteRegStr SHCTX "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\$(^Name)" "DisplayIcon" "$InstDir\MyApp.exe"
WriteRegStr SHCTX "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\$(^Name)" "DisplayName" "My super app"
WriteRegStr SHCTX "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\$(^Name)" "UninstallString" '"$InstDir\UnInst.exe"'
WriteRegStr SHCTX "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\$(^Name)" "QuietUninstallString" '"$InstDir\UnInst.exe" /S'
SectionEnd
```

Comment: EXAMPLE: `WriteRegStr SHCTX "${UninstallKey}" "DisplayIcon" ${MainBinary}`