# is there a way to specify the Add/Remove icon using CPACK + NSIS?

Tags: windows, cmake, nsis, cpack

I see that this is possible using nsis scripting: https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Add_uninstall_information_to_Add/Remove_Programs. There is also an SO post about it (from back in 2013): [NSIS MUI Icon in Programs and Features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254043/nsis-mui-icon-in-programs-and-features)

But in the CPACK NSIS generator documentation I don't see any avenue for specifying the icon in the Control Panel->Programs and Features dialog: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/nsis.html

CMake and CPack can produce really nice nsis installers. AFAICT this is the only thing missing!

Comment: The old post is still correct. No idea how to integrate it with cpack though.

Comment: @Anders (the original answerer?) Yes, NSIS doesn't appear to have changed much since then.

Comment: Also, I found some more issues. `CPACK_NSIS_MUI_HEADERIMAGE` is incorrectly documented. It should be `CPACK_NSIS_MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP`, but as it doesn't appear to actually insert the bitmap into the installer dialog, that doesn't really matter.  `CPACK_NSIS_MUI_WELCOMEFINISH_BITMAP` also appears to do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CPack documentation is not very helpful.

You need to set `CPACK_NSIS_INSTALLED_ICON_NAME` to a .exe or .ico filename (`"$INSTDIR\@CPACK_NSIS_INSTALLED_ICON_NAME@"` is written to the registry)

Comment: Yup! That did it. Any thoughts on how to get CPACK to shove the bitmaps in there?

Comment: Seems to me CPACK_NSIS_MUI_HEADERIMAGE is correct but I don't have CPack so I don't really know.

Comment: Well it causes errors when I use it.